# Python ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, unicode

My dataset file looks like

```
__label__ita Adesso datemi le chiavi.
__label__ara ياله من طفل محبب! يييي!
__label__eng You're a really bad bartender.
__label__epo En kiu hotelo vi restados?
__label__spa Él dijo haber perdido su vigor a los cuarenta.
__label__tat Сиңа булышмакчы идем.
__label__heb את מה פותח המפתח הזה?
__label__eng I caught a glimpse of him from the bus.
__label__eng I advise you to do that today.
__label__jpn この歌の歌い方を教えてくれますか。
__label__deu Ich habe gewusst, dass ihr Tom nicht vergessen würdet.
```

I'm using this function to parse the first column labels

```
def parse_labels(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return np.array( list(map(lambda x: x[9:], f.read().decode('utf-8').split() )) )
```

so I split the row and get the `ita` label from the prefix `__label__ita` by example, but it breaks for some reason

```
test_labels = parse_labels(args.test)
print("Test labels:%d (sample)\n%s" % (len(test_labels),test_labels[:1]) )
print("labels:%s" % test_labels)
```

and I get

```
Test labels:71828 (sample)
[u'ita']
labels:[u'ita' u'' u'' ... u'' u'' u'']
```

while I should have had

```
[u'ita',u'ara',u'eng',...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question does not seem to match the content, and I am answering the question posed in the body.  I made your code a little more modular and tested it.  It returns the desired list that you have at the end of the question (`u'ita',u'ara',u'eng',...]`):

```
def parse_labels(path):
    test_labels = []
    with open(path,'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            test_labels.append(line.decode('utf-8').split(' ')[0][10:])
        return [x for x in test_labels if x] #removes empty strings
parse_labels(args.test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the language codes are at fixed offsets in each line, this can be processed more simply with a list comprehension.  `data.txt` is the UTF-8-encoded input data.  This code will work in Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io

def parse_labels(path):
    with io.open(path,encoding='utf8') as f:
        return [line[9:12] for line in f]

print(parse_labels('data.txt'))
```

Output (Python 3):

```
['ita', 'ara', 'eng', 'epo', 'spa', 'tat', 'heb', 'eng', 'eng', 'jpn', 'deu']
```